# How to get the search words location from Sphinx search engine?

Tags: sql, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I use Sphinx to index HTML pages, giving different weights to title, description, etc. I'm looking for a way to get the search words location in the page from the results that I get from Sphinx.

Meaning, if the wordset is "stack overflow program" and I have 5 documents that match, each of them was a match because it contained at least one word from the wordset.

The question is: how do I know where each word was found in a document? For example, I want to know if document 1 returned because it contained "overflow" in the title and "stack" in the description.

I see that the result returns with a certain weight (3780, for example) but I can't conclude from that on what word was found where.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to (somehow) get the results back programmatically, and then you can call [BuildExcerpts](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts) on the contents. Sphinx will then give you an HTML block with the relative positions of the found text.